# Cannot add foreign key constraint - Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I have posts table:

```
       Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('imid');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('body');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

and

images table:

```
   Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('imid');
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->longText('image_path')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I am trying to add a foreign field to existing posts table in a separate migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('imid')->references('imid')->on('images')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('imid');
        });
    }
```

But when I run

```
php artisan migrate
```

I get error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `posts` add constraint `posts_imid_foreign` foreign key (`imid`) references `images` (`imid`) on delete cascade)
```

It seems I do it right. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that both your tables have the columns for which you create the foreign key (`imid`) and that these columns have the same types. You can use the following commands to do this:

```
DESCRIBE posts;
DESCRIBE images;
```

2. Next, check if `posts` table has no `imid` values which point to non-existing records in the `images` table (If they are - connect them to existing ones or remove them)

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.imid FROM posts
    LEFT JOIN images ON posts.imid = images.imid
    WHERE images.id IS NULL;
```

3. Make sure your tables are using InnoDB engine

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name = 'posts';
```

if `Engine != InnoDB` then run:

```
ALTER TABLE posts ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Finally, I suggest that you change the `down` method of your migration so that it does the reverse of the `up` method:

```
Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropForeign('posts_imid_foreign');
});
```

Comment: Both columns are the same type and DB engine is InnoDB.